# Calculating sample size for difference of mean in exponential data

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power

I want to estimate what sample size I need in an experiment where I compare the mean of an almost exponentially distributed variable between two groups (in an A/B test).

I know I'm always going to have more than 500 samples per variation so I assume that the difference in mean is normally distributed and calculate $z$ as

$$z = \frac{\bar {X}_1 - \bar{X}_2}{s_p \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}}$$

with $$ s_p = \sqrt{\frac{(n_1-1)s_{X_1}^2+(n_2-1)s_{X_2}^2}{n_1+n_2-2}}$$

To calculate the power I followed the [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power#Example) but replaced their standard error, $\hat{\sigma}_D/\sqrt{n}$, with $$SE=s_p\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}$$ which means that I end up with $$1-\beta = power\approx 1- \Phi(z_{\alpha/2}-\frac{\theta}{SE})$$ where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution and $\theta$ is the minimum difference in mean I want to be able to detect with rate $1-\beta$.

For simplicity I assume that $n_1=n_2$ and end up with the expression $n=\frac{2(s_{x_1}^2+s_{x_2}^2)(Z_{\alpha/2}-Z_{1-\beta})^2}{\theta^2}$

To validate this I did the script below where I generate three exponential distributions, one of them, A, with a scale parameter that is $mde$ (minimum detectable effect) higher compared to the other two distributions (B1 and B2). Then in each loop I do two "experiments" where I in one case compare two distributions with the same parameters and one where I compare two distributions with a small difference. Then when counting the number of "significant differences" in the experiments I expect to get false positive rate $\alpha$ when comparing B1 and B2 and true positive rate $1-\beta$ when comparing A with B1. When doing this on sampled distributions where I know all the parameters it seems to work. I get the power and significance I'm using as input.

Now the question is how I would apply this to a real scenario where I only can estimate $s_{x_1}$ and $s_{x_2}$? I tried to do this with some real data by using the standard deviation of all the data for both $s_{x_1}$ and $s_{x_2}$ and ended up really wrong in my sample size calculations (I got a way too high power). Any suggestions on how to approach this in a better way?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, root
%matplotlib inline


def two_sample_z_test(sample1, sample2):
    s_p = np.sqrt(((sample1.size - 1) * sample1.std()**2 + (sample2.size - 1) * sample2.std()**2) /
                  (sample1.size+sample2.size-2))
    z_value = (sample1.mean()-sample2.mean())/(s_p * np.sqrt(1/sample1.size + 1/sample2.size))
    p_value = st.norm.sf(np.abs(z_value), sample1.size + sample2.size - 2) * 2  
    return p_value, z_value


def confidence_interval_normal(sample1, sample2,  alpha = 0.05):
    n1 = sample1.size
    n2 = sample2.size
    std1 = sample1.std()
    std2 = sample2.std()
    df = n1 + n2 - 2
    z_crit = st.norm.isf(q=alpha/2)
    s_p = np.sqrt(((n1 - 1) * std1**2 + (n2 - 1) * std2**2)/df)
    mean_diff = sample1.mean() - sample2.mean()

    ci_width = z_crit*s_p*np.sqrt(1/n1+1/n2)
    ci_lower = mean_diff - ci_width
    ci_upper = mean_diff + ci_width
    return ci_lower, ci_upper

def sample_size_z_test(mde, std1, std2, alpha=0.05, power=0.8):
    #https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power#Example
    z_crit = st.norm.isf(q=alpha/2)
    z_power = st.norm.isf(q=power)

    n = 2*(std1**2+std2**2)*(z_crit-z_power)**2/mde**2

    return n

#Parameters for the distributions
b_mean = 10
mde = 1
a_mean = b_mean + mde
alpha = 0.05
power = 0.8

#Calculate power
sample_size=int(sample_size_z_test(mde=mde, std1=a_mean, std2=b_mean, alpha=alpha, power=power)/2)

n_loops = 5000 #number of "experiments" to run
ci_diff = np.zeros([n_loops,2])
ci_no_diff = np.zeros([n_loops,2])

diff_A_B1 = np.zeros(n_loops)
diff_B1_B2 = np.zeros(n_loops)

za = np.zeros(n_loops)
zb = np.zeros(n_loops)


for i in range(n_loops):
    experiment_A = np.random.exponential(size=sample_size, scale=a_mean)
    experiment_B1 = np.random.exponential(size=sample_size, scale=b_mean)
    experiment_B2 = np.random.exponential(size=sample_size, scale=b_mean)

    pa, za[i] = two_sample_z_test(experiment_A, experiment_B1)
    pb, zb[i] = two_sample_z_test(experiment_B1, experiment_B2)

    ci_diff[i,:] = confidence_interval_normal(sample1=experiment_A, sample2=experiment_B1, alpha=alpha)
    ci_no_diff[i,:] = confidence_interval_normal(sample1=experiment_B1, sample2=experiment_B2, alpha=alpha)

    diff_A_B1[i] = experiment_A.mean() - experiment_B1.mean()
    diff_B1_B2[i] = experiment_B1.mean() - experiment_B2.mean()


#Count how many times we are outside the 95% confidence interval (i.e. a significnace change=positive result)
significant_diff = (ci_diff[:,0]>0) | (ci_diff[:,1]<0)
significant_no_diff = (ci_no_diff[:,0]>0) | (ci_no_diff[:,1]<0)

# In how many "experiments" did we get a confidence interval that did not contain 0?
# This is the false positive rate for the case when there is no difference and true positive rate when 
# there is a difference
positive_rate_improvement = sum(significant_diff)/n_loops
positive_rate_no_diff = sum(significant_no_diff)/n_loops

print('True positive rate: ', positive_rate_improvement, '(chosen power: ', power, 
      ')\nFalse positive rate comparing B1 to B2: ', positive_rate_no_diff, 
      ' (chosen significance level: ', alpha,')')

ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
sns.distplot(diff_A_B1, ax=ax1, label = 'Difference in mean between A and B1')
sns.distplot(diff_B1_B2, ax=ax1, label = 'Difference in mean between B1 and B2')
plt.legend()


x = np.linspace(-6,6,1000)
z_theory = st.norm.pdf(x=x)

ax2 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

sns.distplot(zb, ax=ax2, label = 'actual z values')
ax2.plot(x, z_theory, label='theoretical z-curve')
plt.legend()
```

**EDIT**
It is an exaggeration to say that the data is exponentially distributed. It looks something like this:
[image: Distribution of data]

Comment: Since the mean in a one-parameter exponential is a *scale* parameter, the more typical way to compare means of exponential distributions would be as a a ratio (*does the ratio of scale parameters differ from 1?*). While in sufficiently large samples you would indeed have $\bar{X}$ being approximately normal, the denominator in the t-test will not be independent of the numerator and variance estimate in the denominator will not be the variance times a chi-squared (so the statistic will not have a t-distribution); you'd require larger samples than needed for the numerator to be reasonably normal

Comment: ... but even if you had a sample large enoug that you didn't have to worry about any of that, your power will be lower than some other tests (that is, for a given level of power your chosen test will require a larger sample than a more wisely chosen test).

Comment: How do you know this variable is exponentially distributed?

Comment: My bad, it is not _really_ exponentially distributed (see new fig above). I don't know the true distribution but I thought it was OK to assume that the mean of the distribution will be normally distributed even though the data definitely is not? What would be a more wisely chosen test? Mann-Whitney U test?

Comment: In sufficiently large samples you will have that the difference in means would be close to normally distributed. Let's assume you have $n$ large enough for this to be the case. That's the numerator of the t-statistic (your "z"), but the t-statistic is not just a numerator; it's the behaviour of the ratio that matters. In really large samples you can ignore the distribution of the denominator and just treat the entire expression as normal (a Z test). *However*, this normality simply means that the test will have the right significance level. It will not necessarily mean you have the best power.

Comment: If your data were actually exponential, the likelihood ratio test will have best power in large samples and for a one-tailed test with two independent samples I think that corresponds to an F-test based on the ratio of sample means. For a two tailed test that F test won't be quite right (though it will do well in large samples); you could always consider the asymptotic chi-squared test on minus twice the log of the likelihood ratio itself.

Comment: Having done some simulations, I'll modify my earlier advice (this is slightly better advice so I deleted my comment); if the distribution were not heavier tailed than exponential, on one tailed tests and equal sample sizes the ordinary t-test does fairly well, both on level and power. It's not as good as the F test based on the ratio of means I mentioned but it does quite well all the same, so you should be able to do quite well with standard sample size calculations for the t. I'll try to write some of that up as an answer when I can get some time. However, your tail may be a bit heavier

Comment: Would "standard sample size calculations" be what I'm doing? When searching around for this I find a lot of different sources using different approaches. Most of the ones for binomial data are fairly consistent but I haven't found anything good for continuous data such as in this example.

Comment: I haven't double checked your formula, but your question is doing "large sample" (asymptotic) calculations (Z, not t). I'm suggesting that using the $t$ (i.e. with unknown $\sigma$) should work okay with exponential (as long as $n$ isn't too small). Note that if it were actually exponential the MLE of the standard deviation would be the sample mean rather than the sample sd.

Comment: It is of course easy to use t instead of z when doing the evaluation (but when calculating the sample size it get's much harder since my $z_{\alpha}$ and $Z_{\beta}$ would become t values which depends on the sample size and I would have to use some numerical methods to get an estimate of the required sample size. Do you think that is a better approach than trying to use an approximate analytical solution?

Comment: Oh, and if you do have any reference on any books or sites where sample size determination is discussed I'd really appreciate the tip! When I search myself I only find online calculators or people giving "rule of thumbs" etc or simply disregarding power completely and just focus on the significance level.

Comment: I don't, sorry. I usually just figure it out from scratch when needed (rare for me); and if it's too complicated to do algebraically I start with an approximation and then I use simulation to pin things down a bit better. [As for the distinction between t and Z you can always start with a Z and then work out how much difference a t-makes to the outcome and adjust the sample size and df if needed. But if you want to incorporate the assumption of exponential data, I'd probably start with a Z and then simulate to get a sense of how much difference both the exponential data & the t-statistic make]